# Sybase to SQLserver linkserver errors

Tags: sybase

I have set up a SQL   link server between an SQLserver 2005 on a W2003 R2  and a SYBASE 12.5.0.2 server on a IBM AIX H70 system.
I use the  Sybase ODBC driver 04.20.00.67

The problem is than most of the times (there is no pattern )  when I select rows from a Sybase table I get ONLY ONE  ROW without any error. Please note that there is no problem when I insert rows from SQL server to the SYBASE server

I appreciate any possible solutions...

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting the rows? Is it via

```
select a,b,c FROM LINKED_SERVERNAME.foo.bar.bletch
```

or are you doing 'pass-thru' sql like this

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM foo..bletch') AT LINKED_SERVERNAME
```

I have had way more success with the pass-thru style query: SQL Server does not appear to get what it needs metadata-wise from the Sybase ODBC driver. I was forced to write replacements for the sp_tables_ex and friends family of stored procedures as they did not work for me with linked Sybase dataservers.

pjjH